# Logged-in caches appearing for non-logged-in users

Tags: magento, magento-1.12

I'm getting some strange behavior from Magento's caches, where it will serve the same cached header/blocks for all users...

ie. if John Doe is logged in and is the first to view a specific category page after a cache refresh, `Welcome, John Doe` is saved in the header and then displayed to all customers.  Same goes for cart totals and even store specific product listings.  This causes great confusion, as navigating around the site your cart total will keep changing.

The only thing I can do is disable block and full page caching, but this is slowing down my site.

What would be causing this kind of behavior from Magento's cache system?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about full page cache, but I have worked with Lightspeed module (which is seems similar and have same troubles) and it's used Cache Holes for blocks that should be dynamic